# Docker Swarm with Zookeeper - No elected primary cluster manager

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, docker-swarm

I have been tasked to build a production ready Swarm cluster using Zookeeper as dicovery backend. I used the official documentation for this purpose, https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/. Concerning backend discovery I used this one: https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/. Now I have an issue. When I try to communicate with the swarm, I have this error: No elected primary cluster manager.

This is my setup:

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 with docker Client/Server version 1.12.3, with zookeeper 3.4.9 launch in the same host as my swarm manager. I'm using a two nodes architecture with one swarm manager and one swarm worker

After Docker Engine installation on each node,

```
$ nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &
```

Now on the swarm manager:

```
$ docker run -d -p 4000:4000 swarm manage -H :4000 --replication --advertise <swarm-manager-ip>:4000 zk://<swarm-manager-ip>/swarm
```

On the swarm worker:

```
$ docker run -d swarm join --advertise=<swarm-worker-ip>:2375 zk://<swarm-manager-ip>/swarm
```

Now when I try to see if everything is good, I hit the command below and the result follows.

```
$ docker -H <swarm-manager-ip>:4000 ps -a
Error response from daemon: No elected primary cluster manager
```

When I just do this:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
91c3864ba6ee        swarm               "/swarm manage -H :40"   17 hours ago        Up 19 minutes       2375/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp   swarm-master
```

I can see the swarm master and when I try to see the logs of the swarm node, I can see this:

```
$ docker logs 91c3864ba6ee
time="2016-12-09T20:29:39Z" level=info msg="Initializing discovery without TLS" 
time="2016-12-09T20:29:39Z" level=info msg="Listening for HTTP" addr=":4000" proto=tcp 
time="2016-12-09T20:29:39Z" level=info msg="Leader Election: Cluster leadership lost" 
2016/12/09 20:29:40 Failed to connect to <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: dial tcp <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: i/o timeout
time="2016-12-09T20:29:40Z" level=error msg="zk: could not connect to a server" 
time="2016-12-09T20:29:40Z" level=error msg="zk: could not connect to a server" 
time="2016-12-09T20:29:40Z" level=error msg="Discovery error: zk: could not connect to a server" 
2016/12/09 20:29:42 Failed to connect to <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: dial tcp <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: i/o timeout
time="2016-12-09T20:29:42Z" level=error msg="Discovery error: zk: could not connect to a server" 
2016/12/09 20:29:44 Failed to connect to <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: dial tcp <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: i/o timeout
time="2016-12-09T20:29:44Z" level=error msg="Discovery error: zk: could not connect to a server" 
time="2016-12-09T20:29:44Z" level=error msg="Discovery error: Unexpected watch error" 
2016/12/09 20:29:46 Failed to connect to <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: dial tcp <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: i/o timeout
2016/12/09 20:29:48 Failed to connect to <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: dial tcp <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: i/o timeout
time="2016-12-09T20:29:50Z" level=info msg="Leader Election: Cluster leadership lost" 
2016/12/09 20:29:50 Failed to connect to <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: dial tcp <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: i/o timeout
time="2016-12-09T20:29:50Z" level=error msg="zk: could not connect to a server" 
time="2016-12-09T20:29:50Z" level=error msg="zk: could not connect to a server"
```

But a simple telnet command shows me that my zookeeper host is working. So how do I have a i/o timeout when the swarm try to connect to zookeeper discovery backend?

Comment: Do you realise you're working with the older legacy Swarm? A new "Swarm mode" has been added to docker in version 1.12. I would strongly advise looking into this as it already provides support for application discovery (meaning you don't need zookeeper)

Comment: Thanks for your response O'Connor. I'm going to update.

Comment: You are running Docker 1.12... So why are you still trying to run legacy Swarm on top? You no longer need a back-end like zookeeper to run Swarm.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments there is a new version called `Swarm mode` embedded with Docker since `1.12`. It includes a built-in high-available distributed object store so you don't have to setup an external KV store yourself.

Now regarding your issue with the first version of Swarm, one line caught my attention:

```
2016/12/09 20:29:50 Failed to connect to <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: dial tcp <swarm-manager-ip>:2181: i/o timeout
```

To me it seems that zookeeper is not running on your machine or that you didn't point to the right port.

First check that zookeeper is running on your machine with:

```
ps aux | grep zookeeper
```

You should see a process running.

If not, make sure you create a `zoo.cfg` file in the `conf` directory of your zookeeper installation specifying the right port, for example:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
```

You can look at [This Tutorial](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html) to bootstrap zookeeper.

After this you can run the `zkStart.sh` script to start your zookeeper instance and swarm should now be able to properly connect and register the `Leader` key.

If this still does not work, try downgrading to zookeeper `3.4.6` as this is the last known supported version since the switch to `Docker Swarm Mode`.